# Changing the name of a UserForm object without causing crash

Tags: vba, excel

I have a userform with a listbox named `IMPORTS_BOX` and some corresponding code. I changed the name to `SIMS_BOX`, then went through the code to update each instance of the name. When I tried to save the file, there were some serious crash errors, and the file was ultimately too corrupted to save.

I am wondering what the proper method is for making such changes without ruining the file.

Comment: Sounds like exactly what I would do.  Are you changing each instance of the old name manually? I recommend using `ctrl+h` to do a find and replace to make sure you get every instance.

Comment: I definitely did that yeah. It was a weird result for sure.

Comment: Did you search "Current Project"? Since there may be codes in relation within Workbook/Worksheets/other modules etc.

Comment: yeah, and even still, every reference was confined to its UserForm code. Still not sure what went wrong, but I must have messed up something.